# Update Query Mulfunctioning

Tags: sql-update

I am using The Simple Update Query but it's not working properly. Can anyone help?
Below is the given Code

```
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE directory_websites 
SET site_name ='{$site_name}', site_url ='{$site_url}', 
site_description='{$site_description}', 
site_short_description='{$site_short_description}' WHERE id = '$update_id'");
```

Comment: have you an error message?

Answer (score 0):

May I ask you why for some var you have {} and for some others, like the last one, you don't?

**UPDATE**

This is know as concatenate: For exemple, when a request should look like:

```
"SELECT * from my_table WHERE id='1'"
```

if we replaced the 1 by a var, it's gonna look like:

```
"SELECT * from my_table WHERE id='$1'"
```

but the simple quote are mandatory and at the same time doesn't interpret PHP. So you have to concatenate

```
"SELECT * from my_table WHERE id='".$1."'"
```

Comment: I am dont know i have just followed the one on the net

Comment: Ok, well in this case, I guess it would be something like:

    mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE `directory_websites` 
    SET site_name='".$site_name."', site_url='".$site_url."', 
    site_description='".$site_description."', 
    site_short_description='".$site_short_description."' WHERE id=     '".$update_id."'");
-
Edit: I just cannot put the code in the good format, I'm sorry

Comment: Nice! it is works but i need to know wy have you used "'. before and after the variable ?

Comment: This is know as concatenate:

For exemple, when a request should look like:
SELECT * from `my_table` WHERE id='1'

if we replaced the 1 by a var, it's gonna look like:
SELECT * from `my_table` WHERE id='$1'

but the simple quote are mandatory and at the same time doesn't interpret PHP.
So you have to concatenate

Comment: I updated my main answer so you can see more clearly and validate if your problem is solved :)